# How can I know if something is publishable?

Tags: riemann-zeta, publishing

I have found an approximation for $\zeta(3)$

The result includes a numerical value and an infinite series which I can also give as an infinite product.

The actual value of $\zeta(3)$ and my numerical value differ by about 0.033 meaning my infinite product or sum has a value less than 1, but very close to it.

Upon Checking on the web ...Wikipedia or wolfram do not provide any definitions that seem similar to what I found.

Would my best course of action be to take my work to the professors at my university to know if this is worth publishing or if there is any literature about it?

Thank you all, and apologies if the question is not up to the standards of this website.

Comment: Try to publish it and see what happens. I have given you the mathematical analog of: https://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1986/11/26

Comment: Yes, the best course of action is to ask an expert in the area, and any mathematician at your university should be able to direct you to the best contact in the department. There's a fair chance it may not be of publication quality, but it's also possible a mathematician can give you some advice on how to improve your work, especially if it is original as you say.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, probably not. We already have methods of approximating Apéry's constant, so I don't know if you will bring something new. But, it doesn't hurt to try!